# cascading dropdownlist mvc3, create method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I try to make and cascading dropdownlist: first dropdwonlist for Projects, second dropdownlist for Activities.

Models: project:

```
usinng System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ManyToMany.Models
{

    public enum StatusProject
    {
        Ja,
        Nee
    }

    public class Project
    {
        //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        // [Display(Name= "Number")]
        [Key]
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        // [Display(Name = "Naam")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Naam moet wel ingevuld worden")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // [StringLength(100,ErrorMessage = "U kunt niet meer dan 100 tekens invoeren!! ")]
        // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Korte beschrijving")]
        [Display(Name ="omschrijving" )]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        // [Required(ErrorMessage = "U moet wel het aantal uren opgeven")]
        [Display(Name = "Geplande uren")]
        public decimal PlannedHours { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "eh, prijskaartje?")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
        [Display(Name = "Prijs")]
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public bool Intern { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "project manager")]
        public string projectManager { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Project Code")]
        public string projectCode { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Start Datum")]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Eind datum")]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Actief?")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        // public StatusProject StatusProject { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set;}
        public virtual IEnumerable<Activity>Acitivity  { get; set; }
        //public IEnumerable<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
        //public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Activities { get; set; }

        public Project()
        {
            this.Employees = new List<Employee>();
            this.Acitivity = new List<Activity>();

        }
    }
}
```

Model Activity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ManyToMany.Models
{
    public class Activity
    {
        //[Key]
        //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        //[Display(Name = "Nummer(willekeurig nummer)")]
        [Key]
        public int ActivityID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Naam moet wel ingevuld worden")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Activiteit")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Omschrijving")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "uren")]
        public decimal Hour { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Begin datum")]
        public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }        

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Eind datum")]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tarief")]
        public decimal Tariff { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Actief?")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "project")]
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        //public virtual DbSet<Project> Project { get; set; }
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Hour> Hours { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using System.Collections
@using System.Globalization
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using ManyToMany.Helpers
@using ManyToMany.Controllers
@using ManyToMany.Models


@model ManyToMany.Models.Hour 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/SelectWeek.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/JQueryFixes.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.GetActivities.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ProjectID").change(function () {
            var idDept = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetProjectList", "Hour")', { id: idDept },
                    function (myData) {
                        var select = $("#activity");
                        select.empty();

                        $.each(myData, function (index, itemData) {
                            select.append($('<option/>', {
                                value: itemData.Value,
                                text: itemData.Text
                            }));
                        });
                    });
                });
         });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ProjectID").change();
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Hour</legend>
        <table style="width: 10%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model=> model.Activity.ProjectID,"Project")
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <div class="editor-field">
                         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Activity.Project.ProjectID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Projects as IEnumerable,"ProjectID","Name"),null, new {id ="ProjectID"}) 
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.Activity.Project.Name)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">

                        @Html.LabelFor(model=> model.Activity.Name)
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Activity, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),"ActivityID", "Name"),null, new {id = "activity"}) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.ActivityID)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.Hidden("WeekID", String.Empty)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WeekID)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WeekNumber, "week")
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownList("weeknr",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Html.GetWeekNumbers(), new { onchange = "Selectedchange();" })
                        @Html.Hidden("weeknr", Html.GetWeekNumbers())
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("weeknr")
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.Label("Maandag")
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US").ToString())
                        @Html.TextBox("Monday", Model.Monday.ToString(), new{@readonly = "readonly" }) 
                       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.Monday)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.Label("Dindsdag")
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                         @string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:0.##}", Model.Tuesday)
                        @Html.TextBox("Tuesday", Model.Tuesday.ToString(), new{@readonly = "readonly" }) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.Tuesday)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.Label("woendag")
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                         @string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:0.##}", Model.Wendsday)
                        @Html.TextBox("Wendsday", Model.Wendsday.ToString(), new { @readonly = "readonly" }) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.Wendsday)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.Label("donderdag")
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                         @string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:0.##}", Model.Thursday)
                        @Html.TextBox("Thursday", Model.Thursday.ToString(), new{@readonly = "readonly" }) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.Thursday)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.Label("vrijdag")
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                         @string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:0.##}", Model.Fryday)
                        @Html.TextBox("Fryday", Model.Fryday.ToString(), new{@readonly = "readonly" }) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.Fryday)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.Label("Zaterdag")
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                         @string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:0.##}", Model.Saterday)
                        @Html.TextBox("Saterday", Model.Saterday.ToString(), new{@readonly = "readonly" }) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.Saterday)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.Label("zondag")
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                         @string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:0.##}", Model.Sunday)
                        @Html.TextBox("Sunday", Model.Sunday.ToString(), new{@readonly = "readonly" }) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.Sunday)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>Totaal:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                 Uren:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MondayHours)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MondayHours)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TuesdayHours)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TuesdayHours)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WendsdayHours)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WendsdayHours)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ThursdayHours)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ThursdayHours)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FrydayHours)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FrydayHours)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SaterdayHours)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SaterdayHours)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SundayHOurs)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SundayHOurs)
                    </div>
                </td>
                 <td> 
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBox("0.0",Model.HourTotal, new {@readonly  = "readonly"} )
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HourTotal)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

And Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using ManyToMany.Models;

namespace ManyToMany.Controllers
{ 

    //[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public class HourController : Controller
    {
        private TimeSheetContext db = new TimeSheetContext();
        //
        // GET: /Hour/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Hours = db.Hours.Include(a => a.Activity).Include(a => a.Activity.Project);
            return View(db.Hours.ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public  ActionResult Index(int year)
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Hour/Details/5

        public ViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            Hour hour = db.Hours.Find(id);
            return View(hour);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Hour/Create
        //Just getting the page from URL.Getting the data(Raw data).

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.HourID = new SelectList(db.Hours, "HourID", "HourID");
            ViewBag.Projects = db.Projects.ToList();
            ViewBag.Activities = db.Activities.ToList();
            return View(new Hour());
        }//end method create 

        //[HttpPost]
        //Restricting an action: u also can write: [httpPost]. But then the second dropdownlist doesent work
        //[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public  JsonResult GetProjectList(string id)
        {
            var ProjectList = this.GetProjects(Convert.ToInt32(id));
            //DropdownList always have to get an text and Value
            var myData = ProjectList.Select(p => new SelectListItem
                                                     {
                                                         Text = p.Name,
                                                         Value = p.ActivityID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                                     });
           //JSonRequestBehavior is an security issur. It is protecting against invalid data.
            return Json(myData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }//end method

        //This is for the second dropdownlist: the activities. When a project is selected. The Id of the selected project
        //correspond with the associated Activities.
        private  IEnumerable<Activity> GetProjects(int id)
        {
            //List of activities corresponding with the selected Project
            return db.Activities.Where(p => p.ProjectID == id).ToList();

        }//end method

            //
        // POST: /Hour/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Hour hour)
        {
            Activity temp = new Activity();
            temp = GetProjects(1).FirstOrDefault();
            hour.Activity = temp;
            hour.ActivityID = temp.ActivityID;

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (db.Hours != null) db.Hours.Add(hour);

                    //db.Hours.Add(hour.Monday.Value.ToString("d"));

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //ViewBag.Projects = db.Projects.ToList();
                    //ViewBag.Activities = db.Activities.ToList();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", exception);
            }//end catch exception.

            //Important!! This will mangage that the actuall data will be saved.If u forget this then u only see it in the view!!

            ViewBag.Projects = db.Projects.ToList();
            ViewBag.Activities = db.Activities.ToList();
            return View(hour);
        }//end method

        //
        // GET: /Hour/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Hour hour = db.Hours.Find(id);
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "What a nice name");
            return View(hour);
        }//end method

        //
        // POST: /Hour/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Hour hour)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(hour).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.WeekID = new SelectList(db.Weeks, "WeekID", "WeekID", hour.WeekID);
            ViewBag.Projects = db.Projects.ToList();
            ViewBag.Activities = db.Activities.ToList();
            return View(hour);
        }//end method

        //
        // GET: /Hour/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id, bool? saveChanges)
        {
            if (saveChanges.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Cant save";
            }
            Hour hour = db.Hours.Find(id);
            return View(hour);
        }//end method

        //
        // POST: /Hour/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {            
            Hour hour = db.Hours.Find(id);
            db.Hours.Remove(hour);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }//end method

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }//end method
    }
}
```

It is about the `Edit method(HttpPost)`. U can select an project and associated Activity. But commiting to the database is not possible. Because I get this error:

```
ModelState.IsValid = false.
```

Please can anybody help me??

Comment: It seems ActivityID is null. But how to fix that? THX

Answer (score 0):

If your suspection is right then I am afraid you have done something wrong over here..what is type of Activity?....

```
 <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Activity, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),"ActivityID", "Name"),null, new {id = "activity"}) 
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.ActivityID)
  </div>
```

Please tell me what exactly you want to do with that piece of code.

Till now i think you should behavior like...

```
 <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ActivityID, new SelectList(Model.Activities,"ActivityID", "Name"),null, new {id = "activity"}) 
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.ActivityID)
  </div>
```

In dropdownFor expression the expression should be for the filed in which you want to post that data. I mean if you write model => model.Activity the value will be delivered to Activity and if you write model => model.ActivityID the value will be delivered to ActivityID.

For the first glance it looks like that..if it's not like that.Please share your Hour Modal on which edit view is dependant.So that we can exactly conclude.

Comment: So what I want to archieve is like this: an Acitivy can have 1-or-many hours and and Project can have 1-or-many Activities. So in the create Hour the user can select and Project and then The associated activities are showing and the user select then 1 of the associated Activities.

Comment: I have posted the Hour Controller. U see it?

Comment: Somebody is delecting my post?? Why is this happen??

Answer (score 0):

and this is my Model HOur:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ManyToMany.Models
{
    public class Hour
    {

        //public string Name { get; set; }
        //public string Url { get; set; }
        public int HourID { get; set; }
       // public virtual Week Week { get; set; }
        public int? WeekID { get; set; }
        //[Key]
        public int? ActivityID { get; set; }
        public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }
        //public int ActivtityID { get; set; }






        //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString="{0:c}")]
        //public decimal? Amount { get; set; }


        [ReadOnly(true)]
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public decimal HourTotal { get { return GetTotalHours(); }   }



        public int WeekNumber { get; set; }
        public int yearNumber { get; set; }

        //Properties days:

        public DayOfWeek DayWeek { get; set; }

        //public DateTime DateDay { get; set; }


       [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? Monday { get; set; }
        public int Days { get; set; }


        [DataType(DataType.Date)]//
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? Tuesday { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? Wendsday { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? Thursday { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? Fryday { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? Saterday { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? Sunday { get; set; }
        //End properties days


        //Properties hours:
       // [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.##0.0#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required]
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString= "{0:#,##0.000#}")] 
        public Decimal MondayHours { get; set; }
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required]
        public Decimal TuesdayHours { get; set; }
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required]
        public Decimal WendsdayHours { get; set; }
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required]
        public Decimal ThursdayHours { get; set; }
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required]
        public Decimal FrydayHours { get; set; }
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required]
        public Decimal SaterdayHours { get; set; }
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required]
        public Decimal SundayHOurs { get; set; }

        public string TextMonday { get; set; }
        public string TextTuesday { get; set; }
        public string TextWendsday { get; set; }
        public string TextThursday { get; set; }
        public string TextFryday { get; set; }
        public string TextSaterday { get; set; }
        public string TextSunday { get; set; }





        public decimal GetTotalHours()
        {
            return MondayHours + 
                   TuesdayHours + 
                   WendsdayHours + 
                   ThursdayHours + 
                   FrydayHours + 
                   SaterdayHours +
                   SundayHOurs;
        }




        //public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Hour { get; set; }



        public Hour()
        {

            //Activity = new List<Activity>();

            this.yearNumber = DateTime.Now.Year;

            Days = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday;
            Monday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-Days);
            Tuesday =  DateTime.Now.AddDays(0);// .Monday.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString();//.ToShortDateString());
            Wendsday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);  //DateTime.Parse(Monday.AddDays(2).ToShortDateString());
            Thursday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);    //DateTime.Parse(Monday.AddDays(3).ToShortDateString());
            Fryday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);          //DateTime.Parse(Monday.AddDays(4).ToShortDateString());
            Saterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4);              //DateTime.Parse(Monday.AddDays(5).ToShortDateString());
            Sunday =   DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);             //DateTime.Parse(Monday.AddDays(6).ToShortDateString());

            this.WeekNumber = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oks.....
So replace your activity dropdown with this...

```
 <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Activity.ActivityID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Activities as IEnumerable,"ActivityID","Name"),null, new {id ="Activity"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.ActivityID)
 </div>
```

You are getting ActivityID null error not in Hour model but in Activity model. it's said to be a key so it can't be null when model is binded. The above code will bind it and i hope you will not get any errors in ModelState.

Still if you get any further binding error please let me know in which property in ModelState is throwing error.

Comment: hi thx for replay.But now I get by every project every Activity. I mean the activities are not filteriing with the associated Projects.and still get the error: ModelState.IsValid = false. what is ur email? Then I can sent u the zip files of the project

Comment: But the strange thing is that u have to press twice on the button when the default value is committing to the datbase.

Comment: Hi My emailid is dhrumil4u360@gmail.com . And refer my answer for next solution.

Comment: iv sent u email: niels.fischereinie

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are assigning all activities in controller.In controller [Get] edit action assign ViewBag activities from the Project Object.
But i don't find any Project Property in hour model i mean at the time of saving how you will decide wich project's hour you are saving?..

There is no Viewbag assignment on get method that is the reson you have to press the button twice!

Comment: iv sent u the project u got it? I understand what u mean, but I have this in Hour:  public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; } and in Activity I have  a reference for Project:   public virtual Project Project { get; set; }. Because Activity has 1-or -many hours and project has: 1-or-many Activities. Project is not directly assigned to Hour but it goes first through Activity to Hour.

Comment: U mean the get method of HourContreller? In this method?: public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.HourID = new SelectList(db.Hours, "HourID", "HourID");
            ViewBag.ActivityID = new SelectList(db.Projects);
            ViewBag.ProjectID = new SelectList(db.Activities);
            ViewBag.Projects = db.Projects.ToList();
            ViewBag.Activities = db.Activities.ToList();
            ViewBag.Hours = db.Hours.ToList();
            return View(new Hour());
        }//end method create

Answer (score 0):

I got your emails but i am not able to access your project.Sorry for that.I am trying to get it soon.. Meanwhile i found your problem that....

In View SelectList should be bound with activities which you want to refer.That why here i changed it to Activity.Project.Activity. If you are exposing it in another way you can change it as per your exposure.

If you want activity from specific project only then use this

```
 <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Activity.ActivityID, new SelectList(Model.Activity.Project.Activity as IEnumerable,"ActivityID","Name"),null, new {id ="Activity"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.ActivityID)
 </div>
```

Now your get [GET] Edit method is not supposed to give any data as hour model will give the list of activities.If you want to pass another collection of activity which is out of model then pass in Viewbag.
Then you Hour controller [GET] Edit Method will look like this...

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Hour hour = db.Hours.Find(id);
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "What a nice name");
            return View(hour);
        }
```

Same for the post method if you have taken an extra exercise for binding other than model then you have to repeat it if you have the same view in response.
And post method will look like this....

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Hour hour)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(hour).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.WeekID = new SelectList(db.Weeks, "WeekID", "WeekID", hour.WeekID);
        ViewBag.Projects = db.Projects.ToList();
        ViewBag.Activities = db.Activities.ToList();
        return View(hour);
    }
```

This will solve your project specific activity problem and binding available on twice  posting problem.
UnTill the time i can access your project, Please post your further problem so that i can tell you over here.When ViewModelState says that there is any error it will say the property also so it will be easy to solve.

Comment: HI Drumil, thx for replay, but If I do this:  <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Activity.ActivityID, new SelectList(Model.Activity.Project.Activity as IEnumerable,"ActivityID","Name"),null, new {id ="Activity"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.ActivityID)
 </div> then on this line: Model.Activity.Project.Activity the last Activity a is in red oke, I changed to this: Model.Activity.Project.Activities

Comment: Yeah that's fine...Ultimately you have bind there whatever property you expose....
So Now it's working right?

Comment: I get the error: Model.Activity = null by this line:       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Activity.ActivityID, new SelectList(Model.Activity.Project.Activities as IEnumerable,"ActivityID","Name"),null, new {id ="Activity"})

Comment: I try it like this:<td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Activity.Project.Activities, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),"ActivityID","Name"),null, new {id ="activity"})
                   
 </div> 
                </td> but then the dropdownlist of Activities will become red when I press on the save button

Comment: But how to use ViewModel for Project - Activity. Maybe that is the solution?